# Ubiquitous overexpression line of a gene expressed higher gene expression in leaf but not in seeds

Tags: molecular-biology, molecular-genetics, gene-expression, cloning

I tried to make ubiquitous overexpression lines of a gene using a constitutive promoter vector in plant. I got multiple regenerated plants through tissue cultures.
At T0, T1, T2 leaves tissues, the gene was highly overexpressed with different levels (5-more than 20 fold change against background) in all the plants. However, in seed tissues, some of the lines didn't show any overexpression and other lines had only slight overexpression (1.5 fold change).
Would it be possible? Or, Does this mean the construct has some issues?